# Nested conditions in access query

Tags: ms-access

I have a table with a series of columns that store costs. When generating a report I have a drop-down which lists these columns. By default the report would show all records but if one of the column names is selected from the drop down I would like to only show those records in which that column is greater than zero.

I have been trying to add a condition to the criteria of the query. Something like this (I know this isn't right but should give an idea of what I'm trying to achieve):

```
Iif(FundType = "ThisColumnName", > 0, "*")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well that was actually very easy... Need to buy myself a rubber duck.

```
>IIf([Forms]![Report Menu]![FundType]="column name",0,-1)
```

Comment: @iDevlop Under each of the columns which store the costs. "column name" should correspond with the contents of the drop down - not necessarily with the actual name of the column.